# get user id in feeditem salesforce

Tags: trigger, feeditem

Good morning, I have this trigger to try to retrieve the mention id of a user in a feeditem. I need to send a custom notification to the mentioned user and my trigger has the following error. Does anyone suggest another solution to get this id?

> Mention: execution of AfterInsert caused by: ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Illegal value for parameter: 'feedElementId': (System Code) Trigger.Mention: line 6, column 1

[image: Error Message]

```
trigger Mention on FeedItem (after insert) {
       
String communityId = null;
String feedItemId = '';

ConnectApi.FeedElement feedItem = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElement(communityId, feedItemId);
List<ConnectApi.MessageSegment> messageSegments = feedItem.body.messageSegments;
for (ConnectApi.MessageSegment messageSegment : messageSegments) {
    if (messageSegment instanceof ConnectApi.MentionSegment) {
        ConnectApi.MentionSegment mentionSegment = (ConnectApi.MentionSegment) messageSegment;
        System.debug('Mentioned user name: ' + mentionSegment.name);
        System.debug('Mentioned user id: ' + mentionSegment.record.id);
        //System.debug('Mentioned user user: ' + mentionSegment.user);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through each `FeedItem` in `trigger.new`.

```
for (FeedItem record : trigger.new)
{
    ConnectApi.FeedElement feedItem = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElement(communityId, record.Id);
}
```

Triggers in Salesforce work on *collections* of records, not individual records. It may be worthwhile to read up on the [Bulk Apex Triggers Unit](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) Trailhead module.